# sort by name and then add amount of each object with same name?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

user can create as many instances of Thing as they please. a user inputs a string into the object with a number.

eg of created objects

```
Thing thing1 = new Thing("input1", 3);
Thing thing2 = new Thing("input2", 1);
Thing thing3 = new Thing("input2", 3000);
Thing thing4 = new Thing("input1", 4);
Thing thing5 = new Thing("input4", 200");

ArrayList<Thing> ThingList= new ArrayList<Thing>();

ThingList.add(thing1);
.....
.....
```

I need to have the the program search through an `ArrayList` of Things and output the inputed String with the combined total of all integers with the same inputed string

output example

```
name    count
input1   7
input2   3001
input4   200
```

Im not sure how I can do this without doubling up on inputs with the same name. unless I compare to a name entered by me

what I have done so far (note it can only find and total what I have inputed for it to search.)

```
  for( i= 0; i< ThingList.size(); i++){

      inputedThingCheck = ThingList.get(i).getInputedName();

   //testInput is the input I know for a fact is inside arraylist
   if(inputedThingCheck.equals(testInput)){

       thingTotal = ThingList.get(i).getCount() + thingTotal;
           }
    }
```

I want to know how to have the program search through each Thing object and add to a total the count of all things with the same name, while skipping the Thing that has already been done

Comment: Usually step one in solving questions like these is "use a real data structure that does what you need from your data". By all means use a class that has an internal arraylist, but give it an `insert(Thing)` that keeps the running tally as you insert. That way there is _nothing left to do after adding_, you just ask your manager for the tally and it immediately has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Thing {

    private String key;

    private int value;

    public Thing(String key, int value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Thing [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thing> source = Arrays.asList(
                new Thing("input1", 3), 
                new Thing("input2", 1), 
                new Thing("input2", 3000),
                new Thing("input1", 4), 
                new Thing("input4", 200));

        List<Thing> target = source.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(thing -> thing.key)).entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getValue().stream().reduce((f1, f2) -> new Thing(f1.key, f1.value + f2.value)))
                .map(f -> f.get()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(target);
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can also implement the groupby function for example java 8

```
Map<String, Integer> sum = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Thing::getkey, Collectors.summingInt(Thing::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ArrayList to contain the thing object, I guess it would be easier if we store it as a key, value pair. The key can be the name of the thing, and the value can an array containing the count of that particular key.

```
    ArrayList<Thing> foo = new ArrayList<Thing>();

    foo.add(thing1);
    foo.add(thing2);
    foo.add(thing3);
    foo.add(thing4);
    foo.add(thing5);

    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> ThingList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for (Thing x : foo){
        if (ThingList.containsKey(x.getName())){
            ArrayList value = ThingList.get(x.getName());
            value.add(x.getValue());
        }
        else{
            container = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            container.add(x.getValue());
            ThingList.put(x.getName(), container);
        }

    }

    // Debug to check the key, value pair of ThingList
    // System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ThingList));

    // Loop through ThingList and get the key + sum of its related values
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : ThingList.entrySet()) {

      String key = entry.getKey();
      ArrayList value = entry.getValue();

      int valueSum = 0;
      for (int i=0 ; i < value.size() ; i++){
          valueSum += (Integer)value.get(i);
      }

    // Print the output 
      System.out.println(key + " " + String.valueOf(valueSum));
    }

 }
```